# Display DIV's inline inside another DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a small `E-Commerce website`. I have a DIV floating to the right of the page.

I want to display item's image and the name below the its image.

For now if I remove DIV from this,

```
<div><?php echo $item['item_name'] ?></div>
```

It does show in tile view(all items next to each other but its name show right after the image, **not below**)

```
<div id="list_products">

    <?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>

        <div class="item_wrapper">

            <a href="uploads/<?php echo $item['item_id'] . '.' . $item['item_image_ext'] ?>"><img src="uploads/thumbs/<?php echo $item['item_id'] . '.' . $item['item_image_ext']; ?>" alt="" style="height: 200px; width:200px"/></a>
            <div>
             <?php echo $item['item_name'] ?>
            </div>
       </div>

<?php } ?>

</div>
```

And the `CSS`

```
.item_wrapper{
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline;
}


#list_products{
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
    max-width: 78%;
    margin: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `div` `display: block;`

Here I am targeting the `div` directly. For your site I would give that child `div` a `class` of `.item_name` :)

CSS

```
.item_wrapper div {
display: block;
}
```

This is assuming that your `div`s are set to `display: inline` in some way like in [this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/bF9mA/)

If your divs are floated then you need to tell this div to have no float.

CSS

```
.item_wrapper div {
float: none;
}
```

Like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bF9mA/1/)

Comment: Are either of these helpful?

Comment: Nope ... floating the item_wrapper to left solved the problem

Comment: Interesting, make sure to put your solution as the answer so that this question can be closed :)